# Space of elementary events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need to describe the space of elementary events of the following experiment. Toss a coin. If it comes up tails, then the point is thrown into the unit square. If heads, then the point is thrown on the [0, 1].
I think that the set can be described like:
$$W=\{(x, y)\;|\;0≤x,y≤1\}$$
Am I right?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: "If it comes..."  Ummm... what is "it"?